# Converting a RESTful API response from list to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Currently I have a function (shown below) that makes a GET request from an API that I made myself

```
def get_vehicles(self):
    result = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/vehicles" 
    response = requests.get(result)
    data = response.content
    data_dict = json.loads(data)
    return data_dict
```

The data I got is in this format. Which is a list of dictionary

```
data_dict = [{'colour': 'Black', 'cost': 10, 'latitude': -37.806152, 'longitude': 144.95787, 'rentalStatus': 'True', 'seats': 4, 'user': None, 'vehicleBrand': 'Toyota', 'vehicleID': 1, 'vehicleModel': 'Altis'}, {'colour': 'White', 'cost': 15, 'latitude': -37.803913, 'longitude': 144.964859, 'rentalStatus': 'False', 'seats': 4, 'user': {'firstname': 'Test', 'imageName': None, 'password': 'password', 'surname': 'Ing', 'userID': 15, 'username': 'Testing'}, 'vehicleBrand': 'Honda', 'vehicleID': 3, 'vehicleModel': 'Civic'}]
```

Is it possible to convert it to just a dictionary? Example:

```
data_dict = {'colour': 'Black', 'cost': 10, 'latitude': -37.806152, 'longitude': 144.95787, 'rentalStatus': 'True', 'seats': 4, 'user': None, 'vehicleBrand': 'Toyota', 'vehicleID': 1, 'vehicleModel': 'Altis'}, {'colour': 'White', 'cost': 15, 'latitude': -37.803913, 'longitude': 144.964859, 'rentalStatus': 'False', 'seats': 4, 'user': {'firstname': 'Test', 'imageName': None, 'password': 'password', 'surname': 'Ing', 'userID': 15, 'username': 'Testing'}, 'vehicleBrand': 'Honda', 'vehicleID': 3, 'vehicleModel': 'Civic'}
```

Comment: did you try data_dict[0]?

Comment: The second result isn't a `dict`, it is a `tuple`.

Comment: Yes @vk-code i tried it and it only shows me the first element of the list and there is two in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the second result is a tuple, not a dict.

```
data_dict = {'colour': 'Black', 'cost': 10, 'latitude': -37.806152, 'longitude': 144.95787, 'rentalStatus': 'True', 'seats': 4, 'user': None, 'vehicleBrand': 'Toyota', 'vehicleID': 1, 'vehicleModel': 'Altis'}, {'colour': 'White', 'cost': 15, 'latitude': -37.803913, 'longitude': 144.964859, 'rentalStatus': 'False', 'seats': 4, 'user': {'firstname': 'Test', 'imageName': None, 'password': 'password', 'surname': 'Ing', 'userID': 15, 'username': 'Testing'}, 'vehicleBrand': 'Honda', 'vehicleID': 3, 'vehicleModel': 'Civic'}
print(type(data_dict))
# <class 'tuple'>
```

It is the same as:

```
data_dict = ({'colour': 'Black', 'cost': 10, 'latitude': -37.806152, 'longitude': 144.95787, 'rentalStatus': 'True', 'seats': 4, 'user': None, 'vehicleBrand': 'Toyota', 'vehicleID': 1, 'vehicleModel': 'Altis'}, {'colour': 'White', 'cost': 15, 'latitude': -37.803913, 'longitude': 144.964859, 'rentalStatus': 'False', 'seats': 4, 'user': {'firstname': 'Test', 'imageName': None, 'password': 'password', 'surname': 'Ing', 'userID': 15, 'username': 'Testing'}, 'vehicleBrand': 'Honda', 'vehicleID': 3, 'vehicleModel': 'Civic'})
```

That's why it is a tuple.

If you only want to merge them in a dict,it seems to be impossible because `dict` couldn't have the same keys.But you could merge the value as a list,like:

```
d = {key: list(value) for key, value in zip(data_dict[0].keys(), zip(data_dict[0].values(), data_dict[1].values()))}
print(d)
```

Result(Make sure they has the same length):

```
{
    'colour': ['Black', 'White'],
    'cost': [10, 15],
    'latitude': [-37.806152, -37.803913],
    'longitude': [144.95787, 144.964859],
    'rentalStatus': ['True', 'False'],
    'seats': [4, 4],
    'user': [None, {
        'firstname': 'Test',
        'imageName': None,
        'password': 'password',
        'surname': 'Ing',
        'userID': 15,
        'username': 'Testing'
    }],
    'vehicleBrand': ['Toyota', 'Honda'],
    'vehicleID': [1, 3],
    'vehicleModel': ['Altis', 'Civic']
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up!!! I'm still quite new to flask and python and this helps me to look in a new direction instead of focusing on just blindly trying to convert it into a single dictionary

Answer (score 1):

This a list of dictionaries.

Therefore you can access them using the array syntax: `data_dict[0]` for the first element for example.

Comment: Are you sure there is only one element in the list?

Comment: You're right, I didn't scroll that far across! I have edited my answer for clarity.